# Two Expressions for one objective function in Gurobi

Tags: java, optimization, gurobi, objective-function

With Gurobi (Java), is it possible to write two expressions for one objective function so that only the objective function is subsequently optimized?

More precisely: I have the following objective function:

f = -(a-b)

Both a and b contain my optimization variable. Since the terms are not quite trivial, I am considering splitting both. However, they are not to be optimized individually, but only the objective function (and thus the difference) is to be minimized. Thus, in my opinion, the possibility of multiple objectives falls out, but I can also be wrong. Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Java variable holding a LinExpr for a and b.

Or you can create extra constraints and decision variables. The overhead of adding a few extra constraints and decision variables is very small. This has the advantage you can see a and b in lp and solution files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I'm a bit on the tube. For my optimization I have to specify an equation depending on my optimization variable "x". As already mentioned, there are more complicated equations behind a and b where it is hard enough to "filter out" the optimization variable. Therefore I would have liked to consider a and be separately. But if I now combine a and b as LinExpr with a new variable, the optimization variable is missing again in the objective function?

Comment: Maybe you have a code example for me or I don't understand something correctly. That I need my optimization variable in the objective function is correct or not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying here. I don't think I ever "filter" anything. I assume you mean substituting out. You should not do that either.

Comment: Sorry, the filtering was worded a bit unfortunate. I meant that my objective function must be dependent on the optimization variable...something like -(a-b)*x. But at the moment x is not yet there but is still in a and b, partly linear partly even quadratic with many additional terms including sum() over 12 months. Of course I could write all partial equations in one equation, but I thought that there might be a smarter solution.

Comment: You should not substitute things out. A linear expression may depend on decision variables it does not know the value of. These values are determined by the solver once it solves the complete model.

Comment: I do not want to substitute anything. a = sum(a1(12 months)) and a1 consists again of another equation etc. until I have an equation of the form constant + constant * x....i know that I must write my equation in such a way that it is dependent on the optimization variable x. There is finally only the question whether I can do this for a and b completely separately and can write them for optimization then more simply into an objective function as -(a-b) together or whether I should / must make the formulation of both (a and b) directly in the objective function.

Comment: There are only two possible cases. (1) `a` (and `b`) depend on decision variables. In that case `a` is a LinExpr or `a` is an extra decision variable and the LHS of an extra constraint. (2) `a` does not depend on a decision variable. Then `a` is just data (constant) for the optimization model.

Comment: both a and b depend on the same optimization variable